# removeEvent ItemListener (removeItemListener) from within itemStateChanged doesn't work (StackOverfowError)

Tags: java, swing, events, radio-button, disabled-control

I have the following code, **I cannot use `setEnabled(false)`, because I need to set the background- and foregroundcolor.**

```java
public class RadioButton extends JRadioButton implements ItemListener {
    public RadioButton(String text)
    {
        super(text);

        addItemListener(this);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        synchronized (this) {
            removeItemListener(this);
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                System.out.println("item is selected true [changed]");
                setSelected(false);
            } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                System.out.println("item is selected false [changed]");
                setSelected(true);
            }
            addItemListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This should be a radio button, that can't be changed. Hoever if I try testing the code, it gives me an endless loop printing

> item is selected true [changed]

once...

...and then always

> item is selected false [changed]

until there is a Java `StackOverflowError`.

How can this be? Is the disabling of the ItemListener not working?

If you can then please also show me, how to pack this into a lamda function. I got a `illegal self reference`-error, when trying to put this into a lamda function.

Please correct me, if the title is not correct.

Comment: the removing probably works just fine, but you also add it at the end again

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that is intended. Because I call setSelcted(...) _before_ I add the `ItemListener` again.

Comment: A simpler solution would to replace the `ButtonModel` with one which doesn't change the `isSelected` state

Comment: The question I have is, why?  Why do you need a button which can't be selected but can't be disabled?  The reason I ask is, as a user, I would infuriated if I was presented with a button which was visually intractable, but which wouldn't change state - I'd think something was wrong with the button or the program

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have a programm that asks exam questions and also _evaluates_ them. I change the background-color and foreground-color for the evaluation-radiobuttons and -checkboxes. It is clear from context that they are not meant to be checked by the user, but represent the correct selection. As I explained in the question, if I would use setEnabled(false), I couldn't set background- and foreground-color (also the grey tone is disturbing).

Answer (score 0):

As [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) pointed out, disabling the `AbstractButton` (aka `RadioButton` or `Checkbox`) can be archieved by setting the `ButtonModel` to a custom one always returning a constant value.

MainClass:

```java
radioButtonOrCheckbox.setModel(new ButtonCustomModel(true));
```

ButtonCustomModel:

```java
public class ButtonModel implements javax.swing.ButtonModel {
    protected boolean state;

    public ButtonModel(boolean state)
    {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    // other methods of ButtonModel-interface
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use setEnabled(false), because I need to set the background- and foregroundcolor

This is probably just purely a personal thing, but I have a distinct dislike or UI's which don't conform to establish norms and user expectations.

So, when a button shouldn't be interacted with, it should be disabled.  This is a convention that a user understands immediately.

> I change the background-color and foreground-color for the evaluation-radiobuttons and -checkboxes.

Okay, so you want to decorate the buttons in some way, fair enough

> It is clear from context that they are not meant to be checked by the user

To you perhaps, I'd probably be madly trying to click it, but I'm just that kind of user ;)

Okay, so with just a little but of paying around with the `UIManager`'s default values, it's possible to take more control over how some elements are rendered, for example...

[image: Disabled CheckBox and RadioButton]

```
UIManager.put("RadioButton.disabledText", Color.BLUE);
JRadioButton rb = new JRadioButton("Test");
rb.setOpaque(true);
rb.setBackground(Color.RED);
rb.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
rb.setEnabled(false);

add(rb);

UIManager.put("CheckBox.disabledText", Color.RED);
JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("Test");
cb.setOpaque(true);
cb.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
cb.setForeground(Color.RED);
cb.setEnabled(false);
add(cb);
```

Now, this is just a quick hack.

For me, I might consider doing something different to highlight the correct answer, maybe fading or removing the other questions or use a `LineBorder` to highlight the correct answer or use a `JLabel` and nice big green tick or red cross, as some simple idea off the top of my head.